# Singly Linked List Python Implementation

Tags: python, singly-linked-list

I am trying to get the second to last element from a singly linked list in python. Here is my implementation:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, data, next):
        self.data = data
        self.next = next

def make_arr(xx, arr):
    if xx == None:
        return arr
    else:
        arr.insert(0, xx.data)
        make_arr(xx.next, arr)
```

When I do the following:

```
lst = ListNode(1, ListNode(2, ListNode(3, ListNode(3, None))))
print make_arr(lst, [])[2]
```

I get the error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Apart from your `None` problem, you are building `arr` as a reversed version of your linked list. Was that on purpose?

Comment: Yes, because once I reverse it...I will be able to retrieve the third element of the reversed list which will be the 2nd to last element of the original. (linear algorithm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning `arr` in `make_arr`...

Edit: a version of your code that works

```
def make_arr(xx, arr):
    if xx == None:
        return arr

    # No need for the else, in this case
    arr.insert(0, xx.data)
    return make_arr(xx.next, arr)
```

Comment: Yes... but you have implemented a recursive function, once you get to the the case where `xx == None`, Python goes back one level and sees this: `make_arr(xx.next, arr)`... which does nothing with the returned value, and goes on to return... `None`. And so on until it unwinds.